# Which scenarios might make Chart.js's canvas element resize?

Tags: javascript, html, base64, chart.js

Question, in which scenarios might the canvas element resize?

I'm trying to save the canvas image generated by Chart.js, via sending .toBase64Image() output to the server, the problem is that sometimes the images are being saved in different sizes. So what I did was to create a separate invisible canvas with no animation and fixed height and width, even took into account window.devicePixelRatio (that could possible make the element to resize) but the element is still resizing in some scenarios which escape my sight :/

Relevant code:

```
var canvas = $('<canvas/>');
canvas[0].width = 680;
canvas[0].height = 480;
// Mobile devices with higher devicePixelRatio would cause Chart.js to resize
// the canvas, temporally modifying window.devicePixelRatio to avoid it.
var originalDevicePixelRatio = window.devicePixelRatio;
window.devicePixelRatio = 0;
window.myRadar = new Chart(canvas[0].getContext("2d")).Radar(radarChartData, {
    animation: false,
    showscale: false,
    scaleShowLabels: false,
    showTooltips: false,
    scaleLineWidth: 2,
    pointLabelFontFamily: "Open Sans",
    pointLabelFontColor: "#666",
    pointLabelFontSize : 14,
    pointLabelFontStyle : "600",
    onAnimationComplete: function () {
        radar = this;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: submitUrl,
            data: {'image': radar.toBase64Image()},
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data){
                radar.destroy(); // We dont need this radar anymore.
            }
        });
        window.devicePixelRatio = originalDevicePixelRatio;
    },
});
```

I've read the code and the only thing I found was a retinaScale() function resizing according to window.devicePixelRatio.. which is solved by forcing that value to be 0.

What I'm trying to achieve here is saving the canvas as an image in the server with a standart size. Is there like an optimal or recommended way to do this? All I could come up with was that invisible canvas, maybe there is a better way..

Thanks in advance! Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

As you've discovered, ChartJS resizes your canvas as it feels necessary. It might change the width, height, both or neither so the shape of the final canvas is unpredictable.

One option you might set to limit resizing is:

```
responsive: false,
```

I guess the best you can do is draw the ChartJS canvas to another canvas with your desired size.

Here's a function that will let you draw the ChartJS canvas to the new canvas without causing the chart to be cropped in the process. Warning--untested code that may need tweeking!

```
// create a new canvas of a specified size
function resize(chartCanvas,newWidth,newHeight){
    var newCanvas=document.createElement('canvas');
    var newCtx=newCanvas.getContext('2d');
    var cw=newCanvas.width=newWidth;
    var ch=newCanvas.height=newHeight;
    var iw=chartCanvas.width;
    var ih=chartCanvas.height;
    var scale=scalePreserveAspectRatio(iw,ih,cw,ch);
    newCtx.drawImage(chartCanvas,0,0,iw,ih,0,0,iw*scale,ih*scale);
    return(newCanvas);
}

// calculate a scaling factor that preserves
// the original aspect ratio
function scalePreserveAspectRatio(imgW,imgH,maxW,maxH){
    return(Math.min((maxW/imgW),(maxH/imgH)));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Chart.js global defaults sets responsive as false
`// Boolean - whether or not the chart should be responsive and resize when the browser does.
responsive: false,`

Looks good, played a bit with the code, the thing is that since I'm resizing instead of creating a chartimage with pre-defined size I get some image definition loss. The 'benefits' of drawing another canvas would be getting a good looking image! And because of the purpose of that image I need an image on server that looks good. Nevertheless its a nice workaround that would make sure that image won't resize